# What datatype should be used to store an array in the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table in my database using Visual Studio.
I've got a table for my **Products** (like in online shop) and then I have a table for **Orders**, which should store all products that user has ordered. The problem is that I am not sure which datatype I should use when designing the database to store an array of products in my **Orders** table. [This is what the **Orders** table should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbEtZ.png)

[image]

Comment: This is not what you want to do. You want to have two tables here. Orders and OrderLine.

Comment: Third table ProductionOrders will be your solution

Comment: Thank you. I considered using this method before but I took this example from a book and it never mentions creation of a third table. I will try doing it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `Products` and `Orders` table with relationship between them.

Your `Orders` table should have `Id` column as well (which is `PrimaryKey`)
Then you should create `Products` table, that keeps all the information about products and additionaly `OrderId` which should be used as `Foreign Key` to `Orders` table.

Please look at that link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

It's also worth of checking:
`One To One`, `One To Many`, `Many To Many` relations in SQLServer to have better understanding and design your data store properly.

In your case you need `ProductsOrders` table, `Many To Many` relationship.

Comment: Thank you. I considered using this method before. But this is an example from a book I tried to make and it never mentions creation of a third table.

Comment: to store array in one SQL column, you need to use something like `;` separated string etc. It's not really approach you want to go. What's the book you are getting through?

Comment: I think theu are more focused on JavaScript side of code, and basic backend calls, that might be a reason why they just mentioned what are the data as opposed to how to do db layer step by step. Image you attached looks like type definition not table as well

Comment: Thank you. The image says it is "The Properties Required for the Orders"

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely data type for JavaScript / TypeScript then.

Answer (score 0):

In Relational database, you can create a relationship between 2 tables.

The relationship can be

- 1 to 1 (1 Product - 1 Order)
- 1 to Many (1 Product - 'n' Order)
- Many to Many (n product - 'n' Order)

Based on your scenario, You can choose any of the relationship listed above. While querying from the database, you can easily operate over each order/Product.